# Semi static field in Java application

Tags: java

I have written a web-service application that has in a main class generated random value per request (for logging).

I cannot set it as a static field because next request will override it.

I also cannot pass it to the every class that I use in the main one (as an argument or with setter).

Is it possible to create some semi-static field - visible for one request but not for every other that go to the web-service ?

Comment: > I also cannot pass it to the every class that I use in the main one (as an argument or with setter). Why not? Have you tried a DI framework like [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)? Many dependency injection systems have ways to specify that an injected dependecy is associated with a request or session.

Comment: It will be a huge refactoring task to modify every constructor/method to contain an `UUID` parameter from main class. I would like to avoid it.

I'm using Spring but have no idea how to involve it here (unfortunately I am not familiar with Spring).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely assume that, in the Java EE model, each single request is served by a single thread and that there is no contention by concurrent requests.

Having said that, you can employ a Singleton using a ThreadLocal, let the Servlet populate the value and have the underlying classes access the sigleton without having notion of the threads or the HTTP request context:

```
public class RandomValueHolder {

private static ThreadLocal<Long> randomValue;

public static Long getRandomValue() {
    return randomValue.get();
}

public static void setRandomValue(Long value) {
    randomValue = new ThreadLocal<Long>();
    randomValue.set(value);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `HttpRequest` and store the value as `attribute`

Answer (score 2):

Save the data in the request itself with `Request.setAttribute()` and use the corresponding `Request.getAttribute()` to retrieve it.