# Java : Using static variable to store Application Specifc Data inside a web based Application 

Tags: java

I am working on a existing web based application which uses static map to store   data  specific to the Application .

This is my  code below  which is responsible to store Data inside a `ConcurrentHashMap` as shown below .

```
public class MyClass 

    // Class variable
    private static Map<String, UserThread> usermap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, UserThread>();  

// Inside a Method 
public void userData()
 {
 UserThread  userThread= usermap.get(getLoginId());
 if (userThread == null) {
 userThread = new UserThread();
 userThread.start();
 usermap.put(getLoginId(), userThread);
 }
}
```

The application is working fine , here my question is that  , is this a valid code because can we store Data inside a static variable ?? (Here the Static `ConcurrentHashMap` contains data specific to the Application )

Comment: I'm not saying this is the best idea, but why couldn't you? What are you afraid of? Have you thought about storing it in a servlet context attribute instead?

Comment: what do you mean by "but why couldn't you" ?

Comment: You're asking if you can do the above, although you have already done it, and it's working fine. So, why are you concerned about this code? Why do you fear it might not be a good idea?

Comment: what i meant is that , can i do better than this approach ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With static map, you would run into the risk of memory leak unless you are sure of the life cycle of each entry added to the map, i.e. who would be adding them, how long will the entries stay there and when will they be removed so that they can be claimed during GC. Otherwise, your application will use up the memory and will start throwing OOME.

Comment: Thanks Vikdor , as per the code , when the User logs out or closes the browser , the entry will be removed from the Map . so i guess there is no problem with this .

Comment: That is a problem when there are more number of users with an active session, than the application can hold. That's why caches are used with proper size and eviction policy configured so that you know how much data you hold at max, at any point of time.

Answer (score 2):

Static variables and caches of any kind should be avoided, especially in multi-threaded environments such as web-applications. There are several problems with your code:

1. Do you remove UserThreads from the map? How do you know when they should be removed? What if client's browser crashes? If you don't remove them you are asking for out-of-memory errors after the application is running for some time.
2. Using ConcurrentHashMap in the way you use it is not thread-safe, because it's possible that another thread adds a UserThread between `if (userThread == null)`  and `usermap.put(getLoginId(), userThread);` . Concurent version of HashMap doesn't magically solve all problems with thread-safety as it may seem.
3. Spawning your own threads in a servlet container is not a good idea. There are better ways to do background tasks, but first you need to say what the thread is trying to do.

Generally using any kind of such static caches is bad idea, in any kind of application. In your case it would be much better to keep application-specific data in user's session.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, user which will log in on one machine will have the same session as on the second machine. I bet it's not a good way to do.

I had asked some time ago about [`Semi static field in Java application`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189304/semi-static-field-in-java-application) and Alessandro Santini gave me very nice solution with `ThreadLocal`. Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK it is according to the specification not ok to start your own thread inside a container. You are supposed to use a WorkManager for this. But the only server I know of that actually is enforcing that rule is Websphere Application server.
2. a static variable in principle is ok, of course if you run in an clustered environment each server will have its own instance of the static variable. This might or might not be a problem.

So technically you might be fine.

On the other hand I am really curious what you are trying to achieve with all these threads. If you start one thread per user this is an excellent attack vector for DOS attacks. I also have no idea why you would want to do something like this.

Comment: I was concerned about this point "each server will have its own instance of the static variable" Our application runs in a clustered environment using 5 web servers , but never there has been any problem

Comment: It might be due to the configuration of your load balancer. If it implements 'sticky session' you are fine, but if this changes, or one of the server actually fails ...